# In Indesign when printing doc with transparent logo. The tranparent area is effecting the background colour

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design

I've creating a a4 advert for a magazine in InDesign CS6, I need to bring in a logo from Photoshop. The logo I'm using was originally transparent but was made up of a number of colours. I removed all of the colour so the logo was completely white but keeping the transparent background.

I've saved this .psd file and then placed it into my InDesign document. 
All looks fine onscreen, but  when I come to print the transparent area of the logo is being picked up on the blue background, causing an overprint effect, so it shows up as a slighlty darker blue box shape.

I'm not sure if the issue is with the PSD file I'm reading in or our printer or what?

We have tried importing the artwork as a transparent .PNG, .TIF and .EPS file and it is still not changed.

Comment: What's the `Transparency Blend Space` in InDesign? (Edit menu) What's the color space of the logo?

Comment: Help doc re: flattening https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/flattening-transparent-artwork.html

Answer (score -3):

If you do not actually *need* transparency, you can try a greyscale TIFF, PSD etc. (without any transparency) and then tint it in inDesign.

You use the direct selection tool to set the foreground and background colors to specific swatches.

[random link illustrating technique](http://www.macworld.com/article/1145915/idtint.html)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all. Tinting a greyscale image has literally nothing to do with retaining transparency from Photoshop.

Comment: I understand. However the context of the question suggests this might solve his problem. e.g. he may be using transparency as a clipping path etc. "completely white keeping transparent background" is a little ambiguous.